# Java WatchService locks directory on Windows

Tags: java, windows, watchservice

It seems when you watch a directory using Java's WatchService and then try to rename its parent directory, the renaming will fail with an AccessDeniedException. The directory seems to be sort of locked by the WatchService.

Can be reproduced with:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class WatcherTest {
    @Test
    public void moveWatchedDir(@TempDir Path tempDir) throws Exception {
        Files.createDirectories(tempDir.resolve("dir1/dir2"));

        var watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        tempDir.resolve("dir1/dir2").register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        Files.move(tempDir.resolve("dir1"), tempDir.resolve("dir1_b"));
    }
}
```

Fails with:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Temp\junit14649009910061913524\dir1 -> C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Temp\junit14649009910061913524\dir1_b

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:395)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1426)
    at WatcherTest.moveWatchedDir(WatcherTest.java:13)
```

Tested with OpenJDK 11 & 14 on Windows 10. Trying to rename dir1 in Windows Explorer also fails.
Works as expected on Linux.

Also note, that when the watcher is not registered on dir1/dir2 but only on dir1 it works.

Is this a bug in `OpenJDK`? Looking at some older issues (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153925) it seems that locking of directories should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jurez answer is correct, on Windows the WatchService will lock directories. This is a [known OpenJDK issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7052697) and apparently can't be fixed.

But there is a great workaround. On Windows it is possible to watch an entire directory structure without having to manually register watchers for each sub dir as on Linux.

This should solve this issue in many situations. With this workaround I only need to watch/lock the top level dir, which should not cause issues for users.

Comment: The example code in your answer seems to be gone,could you paste someting here? thx a lot !

Comment: In the above example use ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE instead of the StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_* events

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a bug. It's a design feature of Windows called *mandatory  locking*. There is no way to disable it.

Linux uses *advisory locking* which means it will not block renames or even deletes of the directory.

Comment: If it is generally not possible on Windows to watch a directory structure without locking (and thus blocking renames), how come file sync apps like Dropbox etc can detect changes without causing these kind of effects?

Comment: Good question, perhaps they don't use a persistent handle like WatchService does, but instead scan the directory periodically. Or perhaps they register the WatcherService on top-level directory which does not change. Perhaps there's also another way - if anybody knows, please leave a comment.

Comment: I've found a workaround, see my answer. Thanks for your input!